# How to keep a message within a string instead of showing it on CMD ? python

Tags: python, django, cmd, rabbitmq

What does the channel.basic_consume' function return?
how i can access to message using variable  i want consumed message and show it in browser?
i build django application send message to rabbitmq and consume messsage from it to show message
in browser like chat

```
import pika, sys
global message
def consume(room,username):
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('admin', 'admin')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('192.168.1.14',5672,'/', credentials)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='topic_exchange', exchange_type='topic')
result = channel.queue_declare('', exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue
arr= [room,username]
binding_key ='.'.join([str(i) for i in arr])
channel.queue_bind(exchange='topic_exchange', queue=queue_name, routing_key=binding_key)
print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
  print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))
channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)
global message
#message = 
channel.start_consuming()
return message
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work. You are running a process that is consuming the messages and printing them. Some other process (django) is listening for requests from your browser.

Not sure how you hope it will work, but consider these alternatives-

1. your consumer writes the messages to a file, and django reads that file when it gets a request
2. django connects to the message bus and reads all waiting messages when it gets a request
3. your consumer writes the messages to a database
4. You build a websocket application that can push messages to currently connected browsers when it receives a message